# Modern/ legible edition of Chik’kei Lev

Tags: jewish-books, responsa

Is anyone aware of a modern edition, or transcription, of Rabbi Chaim Palaggi’s responsa Chik’kei Lev? The only edition I can find on Otzar and on HebrewBooks is a scan that’s [barely legible](https://hebrewbooks.org/799). And it doesn’t seem to be on Bar Ilan. Any advice most welcome!

Comment: Have you tried seeing if a physical copy is for sale?

Answer (score 3):

A high-quality, **legible** (*but not modern*) scan can be had at the National Library of Israel.

Here is the [general listing](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH990017551880205171/NLI) for the sefer.

Here is [Volume 1](https://rosetta.nli.org.il/delivery/DeliveryManagerServlet?dps_pid=IE153018218) of the scan and here is [Volume 2](https://rosetta.nli.org.il/delivery/DeliveryManagerServlet?dps_pid=IE153279643).

There are also links on that site for downloading the sefer in either PDF or zipped JPG format (*the latter offering higher resolution*).

Other scans of the sefer that are slightly better than the scans at HebrewBooks are on Google Play. Here are [Volume 1](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=MDZj79uBzgIC) and [Volume 2](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=Mw3Kd8CZryIC).

In terms of a fully digitized version of this sefer, a very incomplete one exists [here at Wikisource](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%A7%D7%A7%D7%99_%D7%9C%D7%91) (*more of a stub*).